# Why ajax callback is called once only?

Tags: 7, ajax

I'm using the following code.

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  switch ($form_id) {
    case 'user_profile_form':
      $form['status_message'] = array(
        '#markup' => '',
        '#weight' => 7,
        '#prefix' => '<div id="status-message">',
        '#suffix' => '</div>'
      );

      $form['validate'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('validate'),
        '#ajax' => array(
        'callback' => 'example_callback',
        'wrapper' => 'status-message',
      ),
      '#limit_validation_errors' => array(),
      '#weight' => 10,
    );

    $form['#group_children']['status_message'] = 'group_settings';
    $form['#group_children']['validate'] = 'group_settings';
    break;
  }
}

function example_callback($form, &$form_state) {
  // ...

  $form['status_message']['#markup'] = '<div class="status messages">settings saved</div>';
  return $form['status_message'];
}
```

When I click on the *Validate* button the first time, the callback function gets called, but when I update the values in the fields and then click again on the *Validate* button without reloading the page, the callback function is not called.

What is the issue with the code?

Comment: $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE; try this because it will rebuild the form

Comment: Is that code in the form definition function, or in the ajax callback function? It's always best to post the function name when posting code, because it gives us context as to what is happening.

Comment: the code is in the form_alter function. I'm altering the user profile form. and I also tried with `$form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE` but same results.

Comment: You are showing the code for the `example_validate()` function, but your AJAX callback is `example_callback()`. Is that a typo? Also, please show the full function you use to alter the form. We cannot answer without seeing the full code you are using.

Comment: @sanzante I have checked it with a watchdog entry.

Comment: @Jaypan I have updated my code.

Comment: I suspect the wrapper is missing on the returned contents, so when the submit is clicked a second time there is no where to insert the new HTML. Check to see if `div#status-message` exists after you have submitted.

Comment: It was my bad. Actually I was display the user profile form on another page. and I have an a condition on path like `if(arg(2) == 'profile-edit')`, and after the ajax request the path becomes `system/ajax` therefore my condition was becomes false and the callback function was not executing.

Comment: Now should I delete the question? OR just put my above comment in the question if it helps someone?